# Get Text Wrap using multicell in same row using fpdf

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pypdf

Trying to get the cells in a single row after wrapping the text using multicell function in pypdf package.

```
from fpdf import FPDF
import pandas as pd


class Tables(FPDF):

    def table(self):
        try:
            self.add_page()
            self.set_font('Times', '', 10.0)
            epw = pdf.w - pdf.l_margin
            col_width = epw/5
            data1 = [{'ip': '192.168.0.1', 'name': 'cloud', 'used_percent': 100.0,'percent': 100.0,'value':6497693752875},
                     {'ip': '192.168.0.2', 'name': 'mitakaDZGFGASSCCGSTHAG', 'used_percent': 97.0, 'percent': 100.0, 'value':6497693752875597265917}]
            df = pd.DataFrame(data1)
            s = df['ip']
            v = df['name']
            c = df['used_percent']
            d = df['percent']
            e = df['value']
            data = [df,[s[0], v[0], c[0], d[0],e[0]], [s[1], v[1], c[1], d[1], e[1]]]
            th = pdf.font_size
            count = 0
            self.set_text_color(0, 0, 0)
            self.set_fill_color(255, 255, 255)
            for row in data:
                count += 1
                for datum in row:
                    if count == 1:
                        self.set_fill_color(70, 130, 180)
                        self.set_font('Times', '', 10)
                        self.cell(col_width, 2*th, str(datum), border=1, align='L', fill=1)
                    else:
                        self.set_font('Times', '', 11)
                        self.multi_cell(col_width, 2*th, str(datum), border=1, align='L', fill=0)
                self.ln(2 * th)
            self.ln(2* th)
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception {e}")

pdf = Tables()
pdf.table()
pdf.output('fpdf_table.pdf', 'F')
```

Expected Output:

[image]

Actual Output:

[image]

Would appreciate any suggestions to get the expected output.

Thanks in advance for your time and effort.

Answer (score -1):

pdf.multi_cell(w,h,txt="text"+'\n'+"text",align='C',border=1)
This will result give you desired output.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33583676)